# Displaytag:column add button(icon) to title

Tags: jsp, grails, gsp, displaytag

I want to add a link(icon) next to my column title in the  tag.
I tried the following but get an error:

```
<display:column title="Workflow<img src=\"blah.png\"/>" property="model.title" maxLength="15" sortable="true" />
```

URI
/Test/admin/deploymentManagement
Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
Message
Expecting '=' after attribute name

Any Suggestions or another way to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using a taglib, because `display:column` is not one of the default grails tags.

And basically you cannot use a tag inside a tag ._.
Since it is a custom taglib, I can only think on 2 options:

1. Modify the taglib code
2. "Append" the image using javascript on the gsp